# Total of correctly predicted in binary classification of images with CNN in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have succeeded build binary classification model for image in CNN using Keras and made the prediction using `model.predict_classes()` and here is my code:

```python
import numpy as np
import os,sys
from keras.models import load_model
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


model = load_model('./potholes16_2.h5')

model.compile (loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metric = ['accuracy'])

path= os.path.abspath("./potholes14/test/positive")



extensions = 'JPG'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,f)):
            f_text, f_ext= os.path.splitext(f)
            f_ext= f_ext[1:].upper()
            if f_ext in extensions:
                print (f)`enter code here`
                img = Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))
                
                new_width  = 200
                new_height = 200
                img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                
                #width, height= image.size
                                
                img = np.reshape(img,[1,new_width,new_height,3])
                classes = model.predict_classes(img)
                print (classes)
```

Now I want to count total of images which correctly predicted, for example how many classes are belong to class 0 or class 1?

Comment: Run inference on your test data in batches. For each batch, insert the output into an array/list. Compute the confusion matrix on the final array

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate that and I'll try it.

Comment: None of the answers good enough to accept and/or upvote?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the `model.evaluate` function; supposing you want to evaluate the data in `x_test` with the ground truth labels in `y_test`, then:

```python
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

`score[0]` will give you the loss (binary cross entropy in your case), while `score[1]` contains the required binary accuracy.

See the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) for more details (scroll down looking for `evaluate`).

Comment: Thanks  for quick respond and I have read the docs but I am still little bit confusing. I am sorry I am quit new in Keras framework,  I mean that I just want to count total of correctly predicted images,which are belong to class 0 or class 1. But anyway I'll try it.

Comment: Are your target data (i.e. labels) one-hot encoded, or simply numbers (0/1)?

Comment: My target data is just simply numbers (0 and 1). In addition,the images that I am going to predict are the real images without any ground truth labels.

Comment: I follow [this reference](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must have the a a sample array of the data you are predicting on correct? well you could load that data as well. Keep the code you have,

```
classes = model.predict_classes(img)
```

yields

```
array([[ 0.94981687],[ 0.57888238],[ 0.58651019],[ 0.30058956],[ 0.21879381]])
```

and your class data looks like this

```
 class_validation = np.array([[1],[0],[0],[0],[1]])
```

Then just find where there equal once rounding `classes`

```
np.where(np.round(classes,0)==class_validation)[0].shape[0]
```

Note: there are many was to write the last line, that assums your numpy array is shape `(number_of_sample,1)`

---

Another way to check

```
totalCorrect = class_validation[((np.round(classes,0) - class_validation)==0)]
print('Correct in Class 1 = ',np.count_nonzero(totalCorrect),'Correct in Class 0 = ',abs(len(totalCorrect)-np.count_nonzero(totalCorrect)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. After I followed exactly what you mentioned above it gave me the total images were belong to class 0 are only 2. Whereas when I count it manually there were 6 images. By the way I follow [this reference](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) to build my model.

Comment: Thanks again for the respond. By the way to make it more clear here is the result of my prediction code.                                                        4.jpeg
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[0]]
1.jpeg
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[1]]
2.jpeg
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[1]]
3.jpeg
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
[[1]]

Count Result
Correct in Class 1 =  2 Correct in Class 0 =  0
Base on the prediction result there are 3 images are belong to class 1 and 1 image is belong to class 0 .So,it still gave me wrong count result